# My switch statement is always returning the first case?

Tags: c, switch-statement, enumerated

I'm having some trouble with this code. I'm pretty new to a switch statements and enumerated types so may be overextending a bit. I managed to work this to enter the switch statement, but it keeps returning the first case. Any ideas why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum express {ADD, SUB, AND, OR, XOR, SHL, SHR};
express m_express;

express switchint(char *str);

int main(){
    unsigned int n1=0x00;
    unsigned int n2=0x00;
    char action[5];
    printf("Enter an expression: ");
    scanf("%x, %s, %x", &n1, action, &n2);
    m_express=switchint(action);
    unsigned int result;
    switch(m_express){

        case ADD:
            printf("add works");
            break;
        case SUB:
            printf("SUB works");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Default");
            break;
     }
}

express switchint(char *str){
    if( strcmp(str, "add")){
        return ADD;
    }
    else if ( strcmp(str, "sub")){
       return SUB;
    }
    else if ( strcmp(str, "and")){
        return AND;
    }
    else if ( strcmp(str, "or")){
        return OR;
    }
    else if ( strcmp(str, "xor")){
        return XOR;
    }
    else if ( strcmp(str, "shl")){
        return SHL;
    }
    else {
        return SHR;
    }
}
```

I haven't written the rest of the switch cases I need yet. Any help solving this issue is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you know what is the meaning of `strcmp` and its return value? Have you used a debugger to step through the code?

Comment: hint: what happens if `switchint` function falls off the end? Also, `strcmp` doesn't work like you think it does.

Comment: You need to read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @o11c - In this particular case it cannot in any way fall off the end. Although I'm not sure how pedantic are compilers at checking that.

Comment: Hm, actually I think the *first* bug is with the call to `scanf` ... the commas in the format string, and then the return value is not checked for failure (not to mention the buffer overflow due to not using `%4s`)

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf`, it may be you are switching based on a bogus value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strcmp` returns 0 if both strings are equal. You should rewrite your checks:

```
if( !strcmp(str, "add")) 
{
}
else if ( !strcmp(str, "sub")){
       return SUB;
}
```

Comment: This turned out to be half the issue. My scanf statement foolishly used commas also. Does this mean !strcmp(...) and strcmp(...)==0 work the same way?

Answer (score 2):

strcmp returns `0` when both strings are equal. So your comparison in your `switchint` function should be:

```
if(!strcmp(str, "add")) { ... }
```

Same goes for the other comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

According to the description of the function in the C Standard (7.23.4.2 The strcmp function)

> 3 **The strcmp function returns an integer** greater than, **equal
>   to**, or less than **zero**, accordingly as **the string pointed to by
>   s1 is** greater than, **equal to**, or less than **the string pointed
>   to by s2**.

So you should write at least like

```
express switchint( const char *str){
                   ^^^^^
    if( strcmp(str, "add") == 0 ){
        return ADD;
    }
    else if ( strcmp(str, "sub") == 0 ){
       return SUB;
    }
    // and so on
```